# In what arc or continuity does Wonder Woman's costume have leggings?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, wonder-woman

There is a concept art which shows her wearing leggings (!) and even a jacket (!!!):

[image]

I also found this picture,

[image]

which looks like a scan, yet I was not able to find a name or a number. Which storyline does that come from? Was it a long run, or just occasional change of wardrobe, like Batman's armored suit?

Comment: I assumed she was wearing pants all the time. But then I'm British

Comment: This image is from [Wonder Woman #600](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/7/71/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_600_Reprint.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120101025815). It looks like the version of her with *trousers* is an alt-worlds story but I'll leave it to someone who's actually read it to post it as an answer since they'll be able to answer your sub-questions.

Comment: Thanks for the issue, I'll take a look. Regarding the *trousers* issue, since English is not my native language, is it appropriate to leave it as it is, or should I actually change the wording?

Comment: @Gallifreian It is fine, pants is American. Trousers is British.

Comment: I think I'll use *leggings* to avoid ambiguity on either continent.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Either are fine here. I was just having a little joke since the word means [something different in the UK](http://h2g2.com/oldblobs/white/73529.gif)

Comment: @Valorum  -  something to keep in mind for my Eng 101 class :)

Comment: @gallifreian - I was very amused when an (American) work colleague told me that he'd wet his pants in the rain.

Comment: I was actually confused by the reference to 'leggings', since she's pictured wearing pants, and leggings are not pants. Pants and trousers are the same thing in the US. You can call them trousers and we should all be clear.

Comment: @DCShannon  -  I am really confused at this point, but I'll still ask what defines leggings and trousers? In the first answer, she's definitely wearing trousers, but since leggings are supposed to be more tight, I reasoned that she was wearing leggings in OP and my answer.

Comment: @Gallifreian It's not super important. I did some research, and was surprised to find that there's actually significant argument in fashion circles about the differences between leggings, pants, and tights. From my understanding, leggings are tights, although maybe a little thicker. They are tight, body hugging, and *thin*. If the material is thick enough that I can't see your underwear lines, I would say that those are pants. I'm not an expert on the subject.

Comment: @DCShannon  -  we can't use the word *pants* so long as Valorum and other brits are here :D I'll leave leggings, since they're too tight to be trousers, and I don't want to call them "tights"

Comment: @Gallifreian - You can use the word pants, just don't expect me to not snigger whenever I read the title.

Comment: @Valorum  -  nah, the image in one of your comments and the story about rain completely ruined it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wonder Woman has had leggings in her costume on two occasions (plus the [answer by Eike Pierstorff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141962/70236)):

1. ***Wonder Woman #600*** (pre-New 52, the picture from OP)

   [image]
    <sub>Click on the images for full resolution</sub>

   This is an alternate reality where gods have left Olympus; after Amazons lost their protection, they were quickly overrun by men, and almost all of the were slaughtered.

   Diana lives among humans with few remaining amazons who train and teach her (I guess her costume helps her to blend in). Her powers are also diminished greatly, although she seemed to be evolving at using them.

   2. ***Wonder Woman #41*** (post-New 52, but pre-Rebirth)

   Diana (somehow) came to be both the Queen of Amazons and the God of War, so she decides to dress appropriately and Hephestos makes her a new suit.

   [image] [image]

   However, she immediately abandons this suit (with no explanation) later when Ares is revived:

   [image]

Answer (score 7):

To address the question from the title rather than the body of the post, Wonder Woman wore trouser in the early 1970s. Somewhere in "[Silent Interviews](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/602455.Silent_Interviews)" [Samuel Delany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_R._Delany), who in 1972 penned Wonder Woman issues 202 und 203 before he was removed (strangely enough due to a protest by Gloria Steinem who complained that WW did not wear her traditional costume; I have to admit that bit makes no sense to me at all), talks about how Wonder Woman at this time was not actually super powered, but more of a secret agent trained in martial arts who would often fight for social issues, including equal rights for women (those changes predate Delaney's involvement with the comic and were quickly rolled back).

And as you can see in the [#203 cover in the Grand Comic Database](http://www.comics.org/issue/25615/) she wore trousers during that arc.

[image]

I'm certain the images in your question are totally unrelated, but the fact that S.Delany wrote Wonder Woman comics is just too funny to pass up.

Comment: OP notwithstanding, this is a pretty legit answer. One thing though: why is the fact that Delany wrote WW comics is funny (I don't know who the guy is)?

Comment: Samuel Delany is a pretty brillant SF writer; he started writing in the 60s and his his career was both helped and hindered by the fact that he is a gay black "postmodern" writer who would often comment in his works on social issues, gay  sexualty etc. in ways that would be wholly inappropriate for comic books.  Imagine Tom Wolfe writing a sequel to "Spot the dog" - that's about the distance between Delanys usual output and the literary requirements of a 23 page comic book. I assume DC hired him to make themselves look a bit progressive.

Comment: Don't worry about the images. Unless you're posting the whole comic, they'll fall under "fair usage"